# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, image, dialog

I am trying to insert images to linearlayout which is inside the dialog.But while running the application i get nullpointer exception error.
I want to know how to get the object of view inside dialog.

Here is my code inside oncreate function.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compinfo);
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_compinfopopup);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().width = AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().height = AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    dialog.show();
    myGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);
    myGallery.addView(insertPhoto("http://www.a.com/demos/img/home/01.jpg"));
    myGallery.addView(insertPhoto("http://www.a.com/demos/img/home/02.jpg"));
    myGallery.addView(insertPhoto("http://www.a.com/demos/img/home/02.jpg"));
    myGallery.addView(insertPhoto("http://www.a.com/demos/img/home/02.jpg"));
}
```

Please help

Comment: You want to add those imageView to your dialog?

Comment: can you post your xml?

Comment: Yes I want to add the image to linear layout inside the dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myGallery = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mygallery);